# Can't use code . and git commands at the same time

Tags: git, cmd, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am on Windows 11 and trying to learn the cmd prompt. I cant use  `code .` and git commands at the same time. If I want to use  `code .`, I have to path it first. After pathing  `code .`, git commands don't work. So, I path them and as a result, I can't use  `code .`. This goes on like this. Is there a solution for this? Thank you all

Comment: What do you mean by `I have to path it first`?

Answer (score 1):

I am on Windows 11 too, and when installing Visual Studio Code, there is an option to add it as a path. Also, with git. To do this manually, you can use this method:

1. Open Start menu and search(type) "Environment Variables" then select "Edit my system environment variables".
2. Once the system properties comes up select "Environment Variables...".
3. On "User variables for ****", select Path and click "Edit".
4. Click new and in the text box enter "C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin". Replace [user] with your username for your C:\Users.
5. Click OK.
6. Now close the "Edit environment variable" window and select "Path" in "System variables" and click "Edit".
7. Click "New" and then enter "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd".
8. Click OK.

Once you have done the above steps both binaries are added to path.

Comment: Thank you so much!!